# If I buy a new copy of Animal Crossing, will it remember my save data?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I lost my retail copy of Animal Crossing, If I get a new cartridge can I resume playing on my 3DS or is that gone for good?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You **can't resume playing** on your current game progress. According to this [nintendo-support site](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/337/~/do-nintendo-3ds-games-save-to-the-sd-card-%2F-microsd-card-%2F-system-memory%3F) the game progress is saved on the cartridge itself.

> While some Game Cards do save SpotPass and StreetPass information
>   to the SD card or system memory, game progress (levels completed,
>   items collected, etc.) is saved to the Nintendo 3DS Game Card.
>
> Note that save data for titles downloaded through the Nintendo eShop
>   (not played on a game card) is saved to the system memory.