# 3DS New Leaf File?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf, nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I have two Nintendo 3DS consoles, and one copy of Animal Crossing New Leaf. I have a town on the first 3DS, but what I fear is that if I put the cartridge in the other 3DS it'll corrupt my save file. The first 3DS has an SD card but the other one doesn't.

If I play the same New Leaf copy on either 3DS console, will the game have separate save files so that I won't corrupt my main file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If I buy a new copy of Animal Crossing, will it remember my save data?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/299062/if-i-buy-a-new-copy-of-animal-crossing-will-it-remember-my-save-data)

Answer (score 2):

All (non-digital-download) Animal Crossing New Leaf save data is stored on the *cartridge*, switching the cartridge between different 3DS consoles will not corrupt your savegame data, and both consoles will load the same save file.

The only thing that *may* change by switching the game between 3DS consoles is some online data, as (I believe) the game uses the *system*'s friendcodes. So you may need to re-register friendcodes on the new system (and have said friends add your second 3DS's friendcode). Streetpass data is also saved to the system, But that (should) only affect *pending* streetpasses that you haven't claimed the rewards for yet.

Comment: I put it in the second 3DS (the one without the SD card) and it gave the option to start a new game, and when I put it back in my original 3DS (the one with the SD card) it loaded my original data. I was afraid to click new game on the second 3DS because I thought of it made a new game there it'll carry over and overwrite my original file I've been using.

Comment: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/299062/if-i-buy-a-new-copy-of-animal-crossing-will-it-remember-my-save-data/299064#299064